# CrudRepository is an interface then why we don't provide the impletion for its method in implemented class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am new Java and spring

(1) I learnt that any abstract method in the interface should provide an implementation in it is implemented, class

(2) has CrudRepository is Interface why we don't provide the implementation for its method like find, save, count, delete

Comment: spring magic writes the implementations on the fly

Comment: @Turo if you read the duplicate, you'll note that it specifically does not **write** the implementations on the fly, as it doesn't generate code but intercepts the calls.

Comment: @Kayaman Again learned something new, but admiring the magic of spring, I didn't care wether code is generated or calls intercepted :-)